# if test -d doesn't found ~/ directory

Tags: bash, shell

I'm doing a script.sh and I have to know if a directory exists. However, when I try to access to check my folder Documents (inside my home directory) if i use the relative path ~/Documents it didn't work. This is my code:

```
function checkDirectory {
    read directory
    if test -d $directory
        then
            echo "exists"
        else echo "doesn't exists"
    fi
 }
 checkDirectory
```

I've tried already with if test -d $directory and if test -d "$directory". I also tried to change first my working directory to "/".

The funny thing is that when I use relative paths as ../ it works! And, what is weirder, the same code written on the shell instead of being executed through
my script file works as well.

I checked this on Mac and Ubuntu.

I've been searching for an answer but all that I've found was or executing the if test on the shell or doing scripts with other language or using relative paths but not with ~/.

Someone knows what I'm missing?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you invoke your script? The `~` should be expanded by globbing in your shell (to value of `$HOME`) ...

Comment: I invoke it using:  $bash script.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `test -d` does not understand the tilde char `~`. For a workaround you can do like this:

```
[STEP 101] # read dir
~/tmp
[STEP 102] # eval "dir=$dir"
[STEP 103] # test -d "$dir" && echo yes
yes
[STEP 104] #
```

Comment: Or better just `case $dir in '~'/*) dir=${HOME}${dir#\~};; esac`

Answer (score 1):

You should correct your script to use some argument (e.g. `$1`) instead of `read`-ing it, then either run

```
 checkDirectory ~
```

or

```
 checkDirectory $HOME
```

You need the `~` to be [globbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) by your shell. You may do the globbing in your script (e.g. with `eval` if you insist on `read`-ing a variable) ; read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

Beware of malicious [code injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) (e.g. the user typing `foo; rm -rf $HOME`)

Read [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the further reading. I didn't know about glob. I need to use the read command because the script is for a class exercise.

Answer (score 0):

you need to evaluate your `~` read from `read` command using `eval` like so:

```
function checkDirectory {
    read directory
    if test -d "`eval echo ${directory//>}`"
        then
            echo "exists"
        else echo "doesn't exists"
    fi
 }
 checkDirectory
```

You might notice an extra `//>` in the code that is done to escape any spaces and output redirections `>` in your command from being executed before hand.

**Edit:**

To answer your comment:

If you are redirecting your input to some file for example:

```
checkDirectory.sh
>>  ~/directory name/path/ > file1.txt
```

here you have a space in your directory name `directory name`. and you are passing the output of your command to a file `file1.txt` using the redirection operator `>`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked! But what are you evaluating when you type echo ${directory//>}?. I've never used this expression before.